# Regex pattern to filter only 2 or more digits

Tags: regex

The entire password length is 8 characters or more, 1 uppercase letter or more,  then everything is OK.

I need a regex pattern to filter 2 or more digits. This is my code but doesn't work the 2 digits:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])).{8,}
```

It allows one or more digits, but I need 2 or more digits.

I also tried this (both none of them work):

```
(?=.*\d{2})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])).{8,}
(?=.*\d){2})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])).{8,}
```

Comment: Could you provide sample valid and invalid strings? And please explain what you mean by *filter 2 or more digits* (allow only 1 digit?).

Comment: This whole thing would be better done without a regex. Just iterate over the characters in the string once, counting the instances of each class of character (based on `isdigit()`, `isalpha()`, etc.) and then write some conditionals to test the rules you want to impose...

Answer (score 2):

To require 2 more digits, just add the `\D*\d` to your first look-ahead:

```
^(?=.*\d\D*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xS5cS2/1)

And it is a good idea to use anchors `^` abd `$` for start and end of string.

Comment: Also, note that this regex is also requiring at least 1 lowercase. Remove `(?=.*[a-z])` to remove this requirement.

Comment: not working, i used this and this:^(?=.*\d\D*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$

Comment: Where and how do you test this expression?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `\d{2}` means two **consecutive** digits and you need to find 2 digits whatever their positions in the string. So basically you can write:

```
(?=.*\d.*\d)
```

You can improve your pattern in this way to limit the regex work:

```
^(?=\D*\d\D*\d)(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z]).{8,}
```

`^` is an anchor for the start of the string, with this anchor, the pattern is only tested from the start of the string (without it, the pattern is tested at each position in the string until the end)

In your case an end of the string anchor is not needed.

`\D` and `\d` are mutually exclusive like `[^A-Z]` and `[A-Z]`. Using `\D` instead of `.*` avoid the regex engine to backtrack.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the requirements are:

- >= 8 characters in length
- >= 1 uppercase letter
- >= 1 digit

In Perl:

```
if ( ( length($password) < 8 ) ||
     ( ( $password =~ tr/A-Z/A-Z/ ) < 1 ) ||
     ( ( $password =~ tr/0-9/0-9/ ) < 1 ) )
{
    # Handle faulty password
}
```

Trying to do everything in one regular expression is error-prone, makes the code obfuscated, makes it difficult to maintain, updating it with further requirements is hard and your colleagues will hate you.